# AWS codebuild remove dev dependencies from Node package during build

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild

I have an application in NodeJS which I am building with AWS CodeBuild and then deploying using SAM to AWS lambda. I want to remove all devDependencies from the project after the build phase. In build phase I run all tests which require the devDependencies but I don't want them to be zipped with other modules while pushing it to S3 as artifacts.

My `buildspec.yml`

```
 version: 0.2

phases:
    install:
        commands:
        # Update libs
            - echo Executing the install phase.
        runtime-versions:
            nodejs: 10
    pre_build:
        commands:
        - npm install
    build:
        commands:
        - echo Executing the build phase.
        - npm run test
        - export BUCKET=alexa-v1
        - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yml --s3-bucket $BUCKET --output-template-file outputtemplate.yml
    post_build:
        commands:
        - echo Build complete

artifacts:
    type: zip
    files:
      - template.yml
      - outputtemplate.yml
```

I am not sure if adding `npm prune --production` in post_build, is the right way to do it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: serverless-dotenv-plugin not found error occrued in aws codebuild. So, when I moved devDependency to dependency, it was installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the same issue.

And in case you think, when you look for NODE_ENV=production
I found out that devDependency is not installing.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the [AWS SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html) instead of the regular AWS CLI. In particular, there is the [sam package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-package.html) command that can be used when you package your application, e.g.

```
sam package \
  --template-file template.yml \
  --s3-bucket $BUCKET \
  --output-template-file outputtemplate.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert "npm prune --production" before the last line in the build phase ("aws cloudformation package...").

This would ensure that all dev dependencies are removed before deploying the code to lambda.